# Gmaps Not working with Jupyter Labs - Error: No provider for: jupyter.extensions.jupyterWidgetRegistry

Tags: google-maps, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gmaps.js

Gmaps works with Jupyter notebook but with a nearly identical setup and with jupyter lab it fails to work. I have installed, done build and have all the basic extensions as I show in screenshots . I have seen one other thread on similar issue but it doesnt solve my problem, i have put all information about extensions and other conda env below.

[image: JupyterLab_and_GMaps_of_the_last_listings_scanned]

```
(regtest) ➜  ~ jupyter nbextension list
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs/regtest/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-gmaps/extension  enabled
      - Validating: OK
```

```
(regtest) ➜  ~ jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v1.0.1
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs/regtest/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v1.0.0  enabled  OK
        jupyter-gmaps v0.8.4  enabled  OK
```

```
(regtest) ➜  ~ conda info

     active environment : regtest
    active env location : /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs/regtest
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/somghosh/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs/regtest/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : /Users/somghosh/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/somghosh/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/somghosh/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/18.5.0 OSX/10.14.4
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
(regtest) ➜  ~ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/somghosh/miniconda3/envs/regtest:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
geojson                   2.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
gmaps                     0.8.4                      py_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h24bf2e0_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.14.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.8.4                      py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_3    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                1.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4
libsodium                 1.0.16            h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h1de35cc_1000    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1
notebook                  5.7.8                    py37_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1b               h01d97ff_2    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.3                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                   py_1001    conda-forge
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.15.2           py37h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                h359304d_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.0.2           py37h2d07e9b_0    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.28.0               ha441bb4_0
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4
zeromq                    4.3.1             h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```

### Code in pic is as below

```py
import ipywidgets
ipywidgets.IntSlider()
locations = [(51.45681, -0.11717),
 (51.49119, -0.07177),
 (51.51439, -0.13108),
 (51.54591, -0.15607)]
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key=API_KEY) # Your Google API key
fig = gmaps.figure()
heatmap_layer = gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations)
fig.add_layer(heatmap_layer)
fig
print(gmaps.__version__); print(ipywidgets.__version__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, not every Jupyter Notebook extension works also with JupyterLab. The reason for that is that the underlying software architecture is quite different, and therefore the code for the Jupyter Notebook extensions leads to errors when running on JupyterLab. For further information on the extensions for JupyterLab you can have a look at the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html).

I could not find an official JupyterLab extension for gmaps now, but maybe you can find an alternative in the recommended [list of JupyterLab extensions](https://github.com/topics/jupyterlab-extension).

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver. The solution was to run `jupyter-notebook` instead of `jupyter-lab` to start my environment.